# How do I set this value? -Getting Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.1 app I am working on for an existing business.  They have a customers table of 10k records.  I am trying to create temp passwords for these users so they can be invited to complete a profile on the new app.

My thinking was to create a temp table (no pun) for the temp passwords so I could avoid storing unhashed password beyond this exercise.

Here is what I am doing thus far;

```
$users = DB::table('customers')->take(10)->get();

    foreach($users as $user){
        $password = str_random(8);
        DB::table('temp_passwords')->insert([
            'custId' => $user->id,
            'tempPass' => $password,
            'hash' => Hash::make($password)
        ]);
        $user->hasPass = 1;
        $user->save();
    }
```

This works as far as generating and hashing the password.  I then thought I would set a flag in the customer table ('hasPass') so I can track what records I need to fetch.

That part is not working;

```
        $user->hasPass = 1;
        $user->save();
```

It gives me - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

2 questions I guess, how can I set the flag for each record in the foreach and/or is there better way to approach this whole challenge?

Thanks!

**HERE ARE THE 2 LOOPS I USED TO SOLVE THIS...**

```
$password = str_random(8);
        DB::table('temp_passwords')->insert([
            'tempPass' => $password,
            'hash' => Hash::make($password)
            ]);
```

**AND THEN...**

```
            $user = Customer::where('hasPass', 0)->first();
        $password = TempPassword::where('custId', '=', '')->first();

        $user['hasPass'] = 1;
        $user->save();

        $password->custId = $user['id'];
        $password->save();
```

For anyone who might have to do the same.

Comment: Should anyone care to hear how I tackled this...

I used 2 for loops. One to generate all the temp password and hashes.  Another to assign them to the users.